# How to convert XML to tab delimited file using generic XSLT without knowing the node

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to ask for your help to create a generic XSLT code that will produce a tab delimited output without knowing the node so that this XSLT code can be reusable.

**XML Input:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <InvoiceInformation xmlns="data.Invoice">
         <InvoiceHeaders>
            <InvoiceID>3</InvoiceID>
            <InvoiceSource>INVOICEFIRM</InvoiceSource>
            <InvoiceNumber>jimt_1235</InvoiceNumber>
            <InvoiceDate>2016-05-25</InvoiceDate>
            <InvoiceAmount>100.00</InvoiceAmount>
            <InvoiceCurrency>USD</InvoiceCurrency>
            <InvoiceType>STANDARD</InvoiceType>
            <LiabilityCoASegments />
            <BusinessUnit>US OBU</BusinessUnit>
            <SupplierNumber>10002</SupplierNumber>
            <SupplierSite>Chicago IL</SupplierSite>
            <PaymentCurrency>USD</PaymentCurrency>
            <PaymentTerm>CHECK</PaymentTerm>
            <Attribute1>DB5 031816INC</Attribute1>
            <Attribute2>0000000057295</Attribute2>
            <FileId>6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00C04FC964FF</FileId>
            <IsImportComplete>true</IsImportComplete>
            <IsCoASegNotFound>false</IsCoASegNotFound>
            <InvoiceDetails>
               <InvoiceDetails>
                  <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
                  <LineDescription>IL/0000000057295</LineDescription>
                  <LineType>ITEM</LineType>
                  <LineAmount>100.00</LineAmount>
                  <DistributionCoASegments>1005-105-70250-8280-0531-00000-1005-00000-00000</DistributionCoASegments>
                  <Attribute2 />
                  <IsCoASegNotFound>false</IsCoASegNotFound>
                  <Payment>
                   <Paymentmode>
                    <Cash>N</Cash>
                    <Eft>N</Eft>
                    <Check>Y</Check>
                         <CheckInfo>
                            <CheckNumber>1111999</CheckNumber>
                         </CheckInfo>
                   </Paymentmode> 
                  </Payment>
               </InvoiceDetails>
               <InvoiceDetails>
                  <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
                  <LineDescription>IL/0000000057296</LineDescription>
                  <LineType>ITEM</LineType>
                  <LineAmount>100.00</LineAmount>
                  <DistributionCoASegments>1005-105-70250-8280-0531-00000-1005-00000-00000</DistributionCoASegments>
                  <Attribute2 />
                  <IsCoASegNotFound>false</IsCoASegNotFound>
                  <Payment>
                   <Paymentmode>
                    <Cash>N</Cash>
                    <Eft>N</Eft>
                    <Check>Y</Check>
                         <CheckInfo>
                            <CheckNumber>2222888</CheckNumber>
                         </CheckInfo>
                   </Paymentmode> 
                  </Payment>
               </InvoiceDetails>
            </InvoiceDetails>
         </InvoiceHeaders>
      </InvoiceInformation>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
3   INVOICEFIRM jimt_1235   2016-05-25  100.00  USD STANDARD        US OBU  10002   Chicago IL  USD CHECK   031816INC   0000000057295   6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00C04FC964FF    true    false
1   IL/0000000057295    ITEM    100.00  1005-105-70250-8280-0531-00000-1005-00000-00000     false
N   N   Y
1111999
2   IL/0000000057296    ITEM    100.00  1005-105-70250-8280-0531-00000-1005-00000-00000     false
N   N   Y
2222888
```

Comment: XML is an *extensible* format, allowing an infinite number of possible schemas. There is no way a single XSLT stylesheet could produce a meaningful result from **any** XML. You need to provide some constraints.

Comment: Is this a real question?  What sort of downstream app do you have that can distinguish between the lines describing invoice headers and the lines describing invoice details, without any record-type information in the record?  In my experience, your "desired output" format is a recipe for tearing of hair and gnashing of teeth at load time.

Comment: My XML is just a example. Not really working on invoice. What I really need is a generic XSLT code that can produce a tab delimited output without knowing the number of nodes. Thank you